# Parse.com code is giving error

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am using code from: https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?app_id=iraven#parse_push/ios/swift/existing

I have Xcode 7.1 running and the code I am using is giving multiple errors.

The errors are; Binary operator "|" cannot be applied to two UIRemoteNotificationType, register for Remote Notification is only available on iOS 8 or newer.

Here is the line of code:

```
if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert |   UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }
```

Comment: Which iOS version are you running in your simulator/device? I am assuming you are using a device since simulators cant receive push anyways

Comment: I have not tested the app. I am getting an error with that code I am using from parse.com

Comment: @DrewBennett just to confirm, when this error showed up, was xcode running the app while an iPhone or iPad connected to your mac?